# Promise callback inside filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to filter an array of custom class data and inside my filter i have conditions to check for.

If (item.name) I do something, if (!item.name) i do something else.  That something else involves a promise.

My issue is, the filtering completes before the promise does, so my promise returns after the filtering is done resulting in missing data.  How do I fix this?

```
    let filteredItems = this.filterItems(items);

    filterItems(items: Item[]): Item[] {
      let filteredItems = items.filter(x => {
        let test = this.filterItemHelper(x);
        // console.log('test', x.name, test);
        return test;
      });
      return (filteredItems);
  }

  filterItemHelper(item: Item) {
      if (item.name) {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText.toLowerCase());
      } else if (!item.name) {
        this.service.myPromiseCall(item, 'itemStore', 'itemIdField').then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          let y = data['itemName'].toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText.toLowerCase());
          console.log(y)
          return y;
        }
      });
      }
  }
```

Comment: @bergi this isnt quite the same. In the example you gave, the promise is called everytime.  Mine is called only if the condition is met.

Comment: That doesn't matter. `filterItemHelper` is asynchronous, so it should always return a promise for the boolean. That the promise will be fulfilled immediately in some of the cases doesn't change the interface.